# How could file size change without 'date modified' getting changed?

Tags: windows, filesize, modified-date

I was puzzled seeing this. My vmware virtual machine was running and I was monitoring the size of the virtual disk file. The size of the file kept increasing but 'last modified' date remained unchanged. How is this possible? Confused.

My host OS is windows vista and guest (which I guess doesn't matter) is Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the last modified date doesn't actually get changed until the file is closed.